# jQuery ajax success method is working in ie8 but not in ie9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using `jquery.Pagination.js` for pagination functionality.

The code is as follows:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var numItems = 69;
                var perPage = 25;
                $("#pagination").pagination({
                    items: numItems,
                itemsOnPage: perPage,
                cssStyle: "light-theme",
                onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                    var startFrom = (perPage * pageNumber - perPage) + 1;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'modules/myModule/models/paginationData.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { start : startFrom , type : 'unassigned' },
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $(".loading_img").show();
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("tbody#unassignedData").html("");
                            $("tbody#unassignedData").html(data);

                            $("body").find("a.summary").popover();

                        },
                            complete: function(){
                        $("img.loading_img").hide();
                    },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

The console says :

> LOG: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"ReferenceError:
>   'FormData' is undefined"}

if `FormData` is `undefined` and is not supported in IE9 so why it is working in IE8 ?

Comment: The error appears unrelated to the code you've shown. Are you trying to create a `FormData` object anywhere in your code base? It's odd that this works in IE8 at all given that `FormData` is only supported in IE10 and higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has resolved.

```
url: 'modules/myModule/models/paginationData.php',
type: 'POST',
data: { start : startFrom , type : 'unassigned' },
```

replaced with

```
url: 'modules/myModule/models/paginationData.php&type=unassigned&start'+startForm,
type: 'GET'
```

Because IE9 does not support FormData.